# How to arrive at correct preconditions and postconditions?

Tags: algorithms

I read about Hoare's logic and algorithm correctness and how mathematicians prove an algorithm is correct,But I think how does one arrive at the required precondition and postcondition?(Inductive generalization).Please suggest further readings on discovering preconditions and postconditions(theorems),I heard about computational thinking and problem solving ,does reading these topics will help regarding this point?

Answer (score 1):

- The postcondition is generally given — it's usually called spec, problem statement etc
- The precondition is also given though usually more implicitly — eg for computing square root, and domain real numbers the input better be non-negative.

Driving the postC **backwards** till you reach the given preC is what the game is about.

If you know your basic axioms of assignment, sequencing and if, and the infra structure of predicate calculus this process too is mechanical *for the most part*.

The one place where this mechanical process gets stuck is loops, where you need cleverness/insight to convert a post-pre pair to loop invariant + variant.

Those insight-heuristics are dealt with in books like

- [Gries](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Science_of_Programming.html?id=CIRQAAAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)
- [Dromey](https://books.google.co.in/books?vid=ISBN9780134340012&redir_esc=y)
- [Cohen](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=PqcpAQAAIAAJ&q=Cohen+programming+90s&dq=Cohen+programming+90s&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)
- [Kaldewaij](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Programming.html?id=4nJqQgAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)
- [Dijkstra, Feijen](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/On_a_Method_of_Multiprogramming.html?id=E2cjSOZuvUoC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)